# Powershell always gives the statement in else as result

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
$eingabe

write-Host "Eingabe Bitte:"
Read-Host = $eingabe

if($eingabe -ge 6) {
    Write-Host "Eingabe war  gleich oder grösser als 6"
} else {
    Write-Host "Eingabe war kleiner als  6"
}

Read-Host
```

no matter what number i enter, it shows the else statement "Eingabe war kliener als 6"(input was less than  6). Which means no matter what i enter the statement in else will be shown as the result...

did i write something wrong ?

Thx for the answers

Comment: You switched sides `Read-Host = $eingabe`  => `$eingabe = Read-Host -Prompt "Eingabe Bitte"` a colon is applied automatically to the prompt. Also keep in mind that in a comparison the RHS (right hand side) is casted to the type of the LHS. So your if will do a string comparison what will have a strange looking result if you enter 50 i.e.

Comment: Thx it worked :)

Comment: should i post it as a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment the entry of 50 will give an odd result:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\26\SO_55869325.ps1

$eingabe = Read-Host -Prompt "Eingabe Bitte"

if($eingabe -ge 6) {
    Write-Host "Eingabe $eingabe war gleich oder grösser als 6"
} else {
    Write-Host "Eingabe $eingabe war kleiner als  6"
}
```

---

```
Eingabe Bitte: 50
Eingabe 50 war kleiner als  6
```

When doing a string comparison character by character is compared until one ends.

So 5 is compared to 6 and 5 is less.

Either explicilty cast $eingabe to [int],[decimal] or [double] or
reverse the logic and let PowerShell cast $Eingabe to an int

```
if (6 -le $Eingabe){...
```